# what is the difference between with or without .loc when using groupby + transform in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, transform, pandas-loc

I am new to python. here is the question I have, which is really weird to me.

A simple data frame looks like:

```
a1=pd.DataFrame({'Hash':[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4],
                 'Card':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]})
```

I need to group a1 by Hash, calculate how many rows in each group, then add one column in a1 to indicate row numbers. So, I want to use groupby + transform.

When I use:

```
a1['CustomerCount']=a1.groupby(['Hash']).transform(lambda x: x.shape[0])
```

The result is correct:

```
   Card  Hash  CustomerCount
0     1     1              2
1     1     1              2
2     2     2              3
3     2     2              3
4     3     2              3
5     3     3              1
6     4     4              2
7     4     4              2
```

But when I use:

```
a1.loc[:,'CustomerCount']=a1.groupby(['Hash']).transform(lambda x: x.shape[0])
```

The result is:

```
   Card  Hash  CustomerCount
0     1     1            NaN
1     1     1            NaN
2     2     2            NaN
3     2     2            NaN
4     3     2            NaN
5     3     3            NaN
6     4     4            NaN
7     4     4            NaN
```

So, why does this happen?

As far as I know, loc and iloc (like a1.loc[:,'CustomerCount']) are better than nothing (like a1['CustomerCount']) so loc and iloc are usually recommanded to use. But why this happens?

Also, I have tried loc and iloc a lot of times to generate a new column in one data frame. They usualy work. So does this have something to do with groupby + transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is how `loc` deals with assigning a `DataFrame` object to a single column.  When you assigned the `DataFrame` with the columns of `Card` it attempted to line up the index and the column name.  The columns didn't line up and you got `NaN`s.  When assigning via direct column access, it determined that it was one column for another and just did it.

### Reduce to a single column

You can resolve this by either reducing the result of the `groupby` operation to just one column thus allowing for easy resolution.

```
a1.loc[:,'CustomerCount'] = a1.groupby(['Hash']).Card.transform('size')
a1

   Hash  Card  CustomerCount
0     1     1              2
1     1     1              2
2     2     2              3
3     2     2              3
4     2     3              3
5     3     3              1
6     4     4              2
7     4     4              2
```

---

### Rename the column

Don't really do this, the other answer is far simpler

```
a1.loc[:, 'CustomerCount'] = a1.groupby('Hash').transform(len).rename(
    columns={'Card': 'CustomerCount'})
a1
```

---

### `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

What I'd actually do

```
f, u = pd.factorize(a1.Hash)
a1['CustomerCount'] = np.bincount(f)[f]
a1
```

Or inline making a copy

```
a1.assign(CustomerCount=(lambda f: np.bincount(f)[f])(pd.factorize(a1.Hash)[0]))

   Hash  Card  CustomerCount
0     1     1              2
1     1     1              2
2     2     2              3
3     2     2              3
4     2     3              3
5     3     3              1
6     4     4              2
7     4     4              2
```